# What does Total lines constitute in ReportGenerator?

Tags: mstest, opencover, reportgenerator

I'm using the opensource tool `ReportGenerator` to show the details of the XML output generated from using `OpenCover` and `mstest`. For one particular project I see the following metrics:

- Covered Lines: 3611
- Uncovered lines: 3587
- Coverable lines: 7198
- **Total lines: 35609**

Ok, `Covered + Uncovered = Coverable lines` and this makes sense. However `Total lines` is significantly above this value and I want to know what constitutes or defines all these additional lines of code to make up `Total lines`.

The documentation for `ReportGenerator` is sparse at best, but I would guess it encompasses commenting, whitespace, things like `using` statements (for importing namespaces), declarations of methods, classes, etc. that are not testable. However I'm not sure, and I plan on using this tool for a lot of projects and need to be able to explain what's behind this number.

Does anyone know or can explain what the `Total lines` value is comprised of beyond the total testable lines?

Comment: I think you've got it, it is, as I've understood it, every line in the source files (code + whitespace + brackets + comments + other) the important stuff is covered/coverable - in the opencover XML it deals with sequence points

Comment: @ShaunWilde - Thank you. I know you contribute on OpenCover according to your bio. You don't by chance have a copy of ReportGenerator to look at the formula that makes the `Total lines` do you?

Comment: According to [Codefile.cs](http://reportgenerator.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#1402884)
it is 
`string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(this.Path);
 this.TotalLines = lines.Length;` and then these are aggregated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Codefile.cs](http://reportgenerator.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#1402884) it is

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(this.Path); 
this.TotalLines = lines.Length;
```

and then these are aggregated at the class/assembly level

However if they are based on files recorded in the PDB then it will not be all your source files there are no sequence points (i.e. a place you can put a break point) that require the file to be recorded in the PDB.

Comment: That was great except I didn't quite understand the following: *"then it will not be all your source files there are no sequence points (i.e. a place you can put a break point) that require the file to be recorded in the PDB."* What did you mean by this exactly? I kind of understood it to mean that if it was the lines as the PDB states it does not include sequence points?

Comment: A PDB only contains reference to files that have at least one sequence point. A file that ONLY has a reference to an `enum` will not be listed in the PDB but is still `source code`. The total lines number is not very valuable and has issues - best to ignore it, or hide it from those it confuses :) .

Comment: Very informative about the differences which I did not know, thank you!

Comment: Just to add some information, I wanted to know if the `.ReadAllLines` method reads blank lines and apparently it does. Therefore if there is a `CRLF` then that line should be read. I agree that the 'total lines' count may not be that useful and better to obfuscate if it confuses too much.

Comment: Thank you, as the author of [OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover) I am glad you find the tool so useful.

Comment: It is A+ awesome yes, I like it a lot :)